# tkz-graph vs tkz-berge

Tags: tkz-graph, tkz-berge

What is the difference between the two packages ? Did they have a different use? I know they have been made from the same author.

The description of tkz-berge says that it pro­vides a col­lec­tion of use­ful macros for draw­ing clas­sic graphs and the description of tkz-graph that is de­signed to cre­ate graph di­a­grams.

I have seen a lot of examples from both packages. They seem to do the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line of the source code for [`tkz-berge`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-berge) is

```
\RequirePackage{tkz-graph,tkz-arith}
```

so it starts off from where `tkz-graph` finishes, so obviously any document using `tkz-graph` could use `tkz-berge` and be using exactly the same package just indirectly loaded. then `tkz-berge` defines additional things not in the base packages.

Comment: So reading the documentation of tkz-berge is enough? Thanks

Comment: @Laxmana I didn't think to look at the doc, I just looked at the source:-) But no I doubt that tkz-berge documents the features of the packages it uses, that would be unusual.

Comment: Actually, there's quite a lot of tkz-berge that is not explained in the doc (when I last looked), so reading the source might also be helpful.